# some complex computation with $(Re + Im) [(1+ i z)^d] = (Re + Im)( 2i z)^{\frac{d}{2}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to show
\begin{align}
(Re + Im) [(1+ i z)^d] = (Re + Im)( 2i z)^{\frac{d}{2}}
\end{align}
where $z^2=1$.

I have no clue for this. If you have any please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that it does not hold for $z=i$, as $1+i^2=0$ and the right hand side is non zero. Moreover $z^2=1$ has as solutions only $\pm 1$. Besides that, when $z$ is real I'd suggest you use the binomial theorem
$$(1+iz)^d=\sum_{k=0}^d{d\choose k}1^{d-k}(iz)^k=\sum_{k=0}^d{d\choose k}i^kz^k$$, and note that $(Re+Im)(i^k)=1$ if $k=0,1\pmod 4$ and $=-1$ if $k=2,3\pmod 4$.

Comment: @b00nheT, i guess your right about $z$, What i start is just $z^2=1$.- I eidt my question!. actually,  I obtained $L.H.S$ from binomial theorem. What i want to do is proceed to R.H.S